# Why does os.path.getsize give me the wrong size?

Tags: python, windows

I have a small html file named `home.html` that I am serving, and I discovered that `os.path.getsize('home.html')` gives a different number than `len(open('home.html').read())`. The number given by `os.path.getsize` is 925, while the number given by `len` is 910. I know 910 is the correct number and not 925 because the page would not display using chrome using 925 but it works perfectly using 910. Can anyone explain to me what is going wrong?

inb4 I don't think it is a unicode thing, since I'm on windows, I'm using python 2.7, the result of `file.read` is an `str` not a `unicode` object, and all the characters in my html are ASCII. Here is the content of `home.html` anyway:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="text-align:center;">
<a href="https://github.com/ChrisCalderon/Yashttpd">
<img style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;border:0;" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a6677b08c955af8400f44c6298f40e7d19cc5b2d/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6769746875622f726962626f6e732f666f726b6d655f72696768745f677261795f3664366436642e706e67" alt="Fork me on GitHub" data-canonical-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_gray_6d6d6d.png">
</a>
<h1>ECHO SERVER</h1>
<p>This is how requests are parsed:</p>
<iframe src="echo" style="border:none;width:40%;height:325px;" scrolling="off">
    If you see the text, your browser doesn't support iframes!
</iframe>
<p>The whole code for this site is <a href="myhandler.html">here</a>!</p>
<p>This is all built with Yashttpd. Find it in my GitHub repository by clicking the ribbon above!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I'd like to mention that `os.path.getsize` seemed to work correctly for serving my favicon.ico file.

Comment: Looks like it's a newline translation problem. 15 newlines and the difference is 15

Comment: open the file in binary mode. `len(open('home.html', 'rb').read())`

Comment: THANK YOU @gnibbler!!!! Answer below and I shall accept it!

Comment: It's ok, just accept Serge's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The file has 15 lines and you get a difference of 15 between the size *on disk* and the size *in memory*. On Windows, the end of line is the sequence `"\r\n"`, but when you read it (unless you use binary mode to open the file) Python (or the underlying routines) transforms those sequence in Python end of line wich is only `"\n"`.

Both values are correct :

- the file is 925 bytes long on disk with lines ended with `\r\n`
- the file is 910 byte long in memory with lines ended with `\n` only

Comment: I had not seen gnibbler commenst (or I would have at least cited it) but the time is clear : he answered before me ...